# Micronaut redirect user to dashboard after login

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-rest

Currently, the login-success property as per the [documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-security/snapshot/guide/configurationreference.html#io.micronaut.security.config.RedirectConfigurationProperties), accepts a String.
I want to redirect a user to their dashboard after login

1. /user/{id}/dashboard

How can I make it so that the user is redirected to their dashboard using RedirectConfigurationProperties?